# How would I fix "undefine reference to @WinMain16" in SDL with sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, sdl

I was following along with Codegropher's tutorial on setting up sublime text for SDL2 and i wrote this short program

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int winmain(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    std::cout << "Hello";
    return 0;

}
```

This should be my GCC command
`g++ -c src/*.cpp -std=c++14 -g -Wall -m32 -I C:/SDL2-w64/include && g++ *.o -o ./bin/debug/main -L C:/SDL2-w64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 && start ./bin/debug/main`
Can anyone tell me what I' doing wrong?

Comment: @AlanBirtles SDL2 has some peculiarities due to its `#define main`, so I updated the dupe link to be SDL-specific.

Comment: OP, rename your function to `main`, and if the problem persists, see the new linked thread.

Comment: Use` WinMain`, not `winmain`, it should have caps.